# What is the flow of operations in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written a simple `Hibernate` program and I am confused with the flow and  with the use of constructors.

This is main POJO class:

```
package mypack;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Emp {

    String name,job;
    int id,salary;

    public Emp()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Inside Default constructor"+this);

    }

    public Emp(String name, String job, int salary) {
        super();
        System.out.println("Inside parameterised constructor"+this);
        this.name = name;
        this.job = job;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Inside Get name"+this);
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Inside set name"+this);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

This is the `ObjectSaver` class :

```
package mypack;

import org.hibernate.*;

public class ObjSaver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Emp e1=new Emp("A","job1",45000);
    Emp e2=new Emp("B","Job2",45035);
    Emp e3=new Emp("C","Job3",44585);
    Emp e4=new Emp("4","Job4",44582545);

    System.out.println("Saving Emp Objects");
    Session session=Myfactory.getSession();
    System.out.println("session obtained");
    Transaction t1=session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Transaction begin");
    session.save(e1);
    session.save(e2);
    session.save(e3);
    session.save(e4);
    t1.commit();
    session.close();

    System.out.println("Successfully Saved");
    }

}
```

`MyFactory` Class:

```
package mypack;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Myfactory 
{
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Loading configuration...");
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure();
        //Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        System.out.println("Configuration loaded");
         factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println("SessionFactory Created");

    }

    public static  Session getSession()
    {
        System.out.println("returning session");
        return factory.openSession();
    }
}
```

Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
 <hibernate-mapping>


 <class name="mypack.Emp" table="Employee">

 <id name="id"  type="int">
 <generator class="increment"/>
 </id>

 <property name="name"/>
 <property name="job"/>
 <property name="salary"/>

 </class>

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Output:

```
Inside parameterised constructormypack.Emp@1bab50a
Inside parameterised constructormypack.Emp@c3c749
Inside parameterised constructormypack.Emp@150bd4d
Inside parameterised constructormypack.Emp@1bc4459
Saving Emp Objects
Loading configuration...
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Configuration loaded
Inside Default constructormypack.Emp@fdb00d
Inside Default constructormypack.Emp$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$aa36f81a@17a4989
Inside Default constructormypack.Emp@659db7
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@659db7
Inside set namemypack.Emp@659db7
SessionFactory Created
returning session
session obtained
Transaction begin
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@1bab50a
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@c3c749
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@150bd4d
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@1bc4459
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@1bab50a
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@c3c749
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@150bd4d
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@1bc4459
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@150bd4d
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@c3c749
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@1bc4459
Inside Get namemypack.Emp@1bab50a
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name, job, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name, job, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name, job, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name, job, salary, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Successfully Saved
```

Why did the default constructor run three times? Why did the setter and getter run just after the default contructor? Could anyone explain the flow?

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate` requires the no-argument constructor for all persistent classes.
Because `Hibernate` creates objects for you using Java Reflection, which calls the default constructor, your default constructor is getting called for each of the objects that you are persisting using the save method.

`Hibernate` uses setter methods to initialize the entity whenever you're reading from your DB and uses getter methods to get the actual value to be persisted whenever you're persisting to DB.

Since you are only persisting it should call only getters.

Comment: 4 objects are being persisted and the default constructor is only called 3 times - also if the order of the logging statements is accurate the default constructors are called prior to persisting.

Comment: There are four objects i have created right? Default constructor runs three times. Does hibernate create proxy objects using default constructor and save those in a session which is used when we try to load the data from db?

Comment: yes Hibernate maintains primary level cache within a session and creates proxy object and it uses default no arg constructor for that.But in the above program  i am expecting default arg constructor to execute 4 times but its showing only 3 times, can you please run the program once and see it...

Comment: Result is same,Constructor runs three times.

Comment: Can you put a debug point inside a constructor and see after which line it is coming to constructor...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log you posted, the constructor is being invoked when the SessionFactory is bootstrapped.  When Hibernate starts up, it instantiates your entities to determine which value should be used to represent the unsaved (default) value for your identifier property.  I would imagine this could happen multiple times based on which entity persister Hibernate is using for your mapping.  It would help to have more information about your exact mapping to know why this happened three times.  If you're truly interested, you can trace the code from:

`org.hibernate.engine.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(...)`

Or just set a break-point in your constructor.